# including header.php and footer.php automatically

Tags: php, html, frameworks

I have been trying to search a solution online and on stackoverflow but did not come across any satisfactory solution.

I wanted to know how can i include (**if required**) `header.php` and `footer.php` automatically in the new PHP pages that i create, at present whenever i create a new PHP file i manually add `header.php` on top and `footer.php` at the bottom, I dont really have a problem with doing this but i was wondering if this is how everyone does it and if not what is the best solution to this.

I know I could takeup any framework out there and use that because may be they include the header and footer automatically, but i am referring to custom PHP coding.

I will really appreciate views of experienced developers out there.

Comment: You can use a template engine like Smarty and use layouts. That way you only include header, footer once in layout. See this link http://tatey.com/2009/04/12/layouts-with-smarty/

Comment: @JayBhatt thanks, but i really interested in PHP alone, no frameworks or template engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach is to use [the front controller design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern).

Use a single PHP file to load all the pages. Have it include the header and footer and use the URL (and whatever other information you like) to determine which content to include.

PHP developers often use `mod_rewrite` to map URLs onto a single script. You could also use the Apache `alias` directive.

Comment: now that I know what it is actually called, i will do some Googling on it, thanks @Quentin